# I'm getting a runtime error in this merge sort algorithm code

Tags: c++11, recursion, c++14, c++17, mergesort

I'm getting a runtime error in this code. This code is for the merge sort algorithm. How can I find the error?

This code uses recursions and functions.  The function mergesort is called recursively to divide the array till its size is reduced to 1. Then multiple arrays are merged using the merge function.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void merge(int l[],int size1,int r[],int size2,int input[],int size){
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        while(i<size1 && j<size2){
            if(l[i]<=r[j]){
                input[k]=l[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
            else{
                input[k]=r[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while(i<size1){
            input[k]=l[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while (j<size2){
            input[k]=r[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    void mergesort(int input[],int size){
        if(size<2){
            return;
        }
        int mid= size/2;
        int l[500];
        int r[500];
        for(int i=0;i<mid-1;i++){
            l[i]=input[i];
        }
        for(int j=mid;j<size-1;j++){
            r[j-mid]=input[j];
        }
        mergesort(l,mid);
        mergesort(r,size-mid);
        merge(l,mid,r,size-mid,input,size);
    
    
    }
    
    int main() {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[1000];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        mergesort(arr,n);
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
        }
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the input you are providing? Consider running the code in a debugger so you can see what is happening.

Comment: I am guessing that `for(int i=0;i<mid-1;i++)` needs to be `for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)`

Comment: @RSahu Same with `for(int j=mid;j<size-1;j++){`. That at least copies all of the data but the result is still incorrect. I stopped there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following errors in your code.

1. `for(int i=0;i<mid-1;i++)` needs to be `for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)`
2. `for(int j=mid;j<size-1;j++)` needs to be `for(int j=mid;j<size;j++)`
3. You are incrementing `k` in `merge` incorrectly.

   The loop

   ```
   while(i<size1 && j<size2){
      if(l[i]<=r[j]){
         input[k]=l[i];
         k++;
         i++;
      }
      else{
         input[k]=r[j];
         j++;
      }
      k++;
   }
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   while(i<size1 && j<size2){
      if(l[i]<=r[j]){
         input[k]=l[i];
         //  k++; This is an error.
         i++;
      }
      else{
         input[k]=r[j];
         j++;
      }
      k++;
   }
   ```